# Load CSV data to HBase using pig or hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-pig, hbasestorage

Hi I have created a pig script which loads data into hbase. My csv file is stored into hadoop location at `/hbase_tables/zip.csv`

Pig Script

---

```
register /home/hduser/pig-0.12.0/lib/pig-0.8.0-core.jar;
A = LOAD '/hbase_tables/zip.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:chararray, zip:chararray, desc1:chararray, desc2:chararray, income:chararray);
STORE A INTO 'hbase://mydata' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('zip:zip,desc:desc1,desc:desc2,income:income');
```

---

when i execute it gives below error

---

### Pig Stack Trace

```
ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.

org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobCreationException: ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:667)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:256)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:147)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.execute(HExecutionEngine.java:378)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1198)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1190)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.access$100(PigServer.java:128)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.execute(PigServer.java:1517)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatchEx(PigServer.java:362)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:329)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:112)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:169)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:141)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:90)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:510)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:107)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: hbase://mydata_logs
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:45)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:470)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: hbase://mydata_logs
        at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1804)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:752)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:145)
        ... 23 more
```

Please let me know how i can import csv data file into hbase or if you have any alternate solution.

Comment: You need to import required libraries to the PIG script. [Refer the following link which will may help you](http://andyamick.com/using-pig-to-load-hbase-tables/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your problem is with "Relative path" in absolute URI: hbase://mydata_logs.
Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: I don't know the hbase:// is correct or not. But i am worrying about it that i am creating table named as mydata so why the issue is looking for mydata_logs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably table `mydata_logs` does not exist. Start: `hbase shell` and type `list`. Is your table `mydata_logs` on the list?

Comment: My Table name is mydata and i put mydata in my ppig script as well why it's looking for mydata_logs

Comment: Anyway, can you provide result of list from hbase shell?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same task once and have fully-working solution (actually, I'm not sure about commas in your third line of the code):

```
%default hbase_home `echo \$HBASE_HOME`;
%default tmp '/user/alexander/tmp/users_dump/k14'

set zookeeper.znode.parent '/hbase-unsecure';
set hbase.zookeeper.quorum 'dmp-hbase.local';

register $hbase_home/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar;
register $hbase_home/hbase-0.94.20.jar;

UsersHdfs = LOAD '$tmp' using PigStorage('\t', '-schema');
store UsersHdfs into 'hbase://user_test' using
    org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
        'id:DEFAULT id:last_modified birth:year gender:female gender:male','-caster HBaseBinaryConverter'
);
```

That code works for me, maybe the matter is in you hbase configs.
You could provide your .csv file and we could talk about it in more details.